# ScrollToTop on Statusbar click

Tags: reactjs

If a user clicks on the statusbar on a mobile device most websites usually scroll to top. How can I do this with react and nextjs? 
Pretty hard to find anything that is not referring to react-native.

[image: StatusBar]

Comment: What is this "status-bar" you're referring to? Can you manage an example, please?

Comment: @niksn can you give example of some website with this feature?

Comment: This is an OS/browser feature that's not controllable from JavaScript. Unless you have some kind of custom scroll feature or the content is in an iframe, the site scrolls to top automatically on status bar tap.

Answer (score -2):

Using this you will take to top from anywhere

```
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

use this in your function which you call `onclick` (call on statusbar() click)